# wikidata get all properties with labels and values of an item

Tags: database, sparql, wikidata

My question is how I can extract all properties and their respective labels that are also rendered on the webpage from wikidata preferably over SPARQL.

Take for example the [Google](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q95) entry on wikidata. For the property P414 (stock exchange) or P159 there are subproperties like P969 (located at street address). They actually show up once you [query](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q95&props=claims) `wbgetentities` as qualifieres. The problem with `wbgetentities` is that the labels are missing. I get the desired output (e.g. `wdt:P17 => country => United States of America`) with the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?prop_id ?prop_label ?prop_val_label WHERE {
  VALUES (?company) {
    (wd:Q95)
  }
  ?company ?prop_id ?company_item.
  ?wd wikibase:directClaim ?prop_id.
  ?wd rdfs:label ?prop_label.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?company_item rdfs:label ?prop_val.
    FILTER((LANG(?prop_val)) = "en")
  }
  BIND(COALESCE(?prop_val, ?companyItem) AS ?prop_val_label)
  FILTER((LANG(?prop_label)) = "en")
}
```

But those "subproperties" are missing because they are not under direct claims. To extract a single statements qualifier I can do:

```
SELECT ?company ?hq ?country WHERE {
  wd:Q95 p:P159 ?company.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?company ps:P159 ?hq.
    ?company pq:P17 ?country. 
  }
}
```

But the question is if there is a way to combine everything to one query?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Useful links on the Wikidata data model:

- [RDF dump format](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format)
- [Wikidata qualifiers, references and ranks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Qualifiers,_References_and_Ranks)
- [Help:qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Qualifiers)

Your query should be of this kind:

```
SELECT ?wdLabel ?ps_Label ?wdpqLabel ?pq_Label {
  VALUES (?company) {(wd:Q95)}

  ?company ?p ?statement .
  ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .

  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.
  ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.

  OPTIONAL {
  ?statement ?pq ?pq_ .
  ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq .
  }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
} ORDER BY ?wd ?statement ?ps_
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FwdLabel%20%3Fps_Label%20%3FwdpqLabel%20%3Fpq_Label%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20(%3Fcompany)%20%7B(wd%3AQ95)%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20%3Fp%20%3Fstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20%3Fps%20%3Fps_%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3Fp.%0A%20%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fps.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20%3Fpq%20%3Fpq_%20.%0A%20%20%3Fwdpq%20wikibase%3Aqualifier%20%3Fpq%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fwd%20%3Fstatement%20%3Fps_)

Only qualifiers and their values are included in the result. Neither provenance references nor value annotations (e.g. time precision) are included.  Please write a comment if you need to add them.

Comment: A question about the SPARQL snippet: Would it be possible to add the entity nodes object ID for all of the returned data. To be precise: For your example with Google: 
wdLabel | founded by
ps_Label | Larry Page
would it be possible to return also the ID of ps_Label and pq_Label
(if they are entities)?

Comment: @fabmeyer, like this: https://w.wiki/7N$B ?

Comment: Genius! Where can I learn that properly?

Comment: @fabmeyer, that's basic SPARQL. The label service is WDQS extensions. More info on Wikibase RDF dump format: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format