# How to get property label in one query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get the label of subject and label of property as well. Using the SERVICE I got subject label but I can't get the property label with the same way. in the column of pLabel, uri path is shown which is not expected. How I can get the label of subject and property together in one query? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?sLabel ?p ?pLabel {
  BIND (wd:Q506 AS ?s)

  ?s ?p ?o .  
  {[] wikibase:claim ?p } 
  UNION {
    VALUES (?p) {(rdfs:label) 
                 (skos:altLabel) 
                 (schema:description) 
                 (schema:dateModified) 
                 (schema:version) 
                 (wikibase:timestamp) 
                 (wikibase:identifiers) 
                 (wikibase:statements) 
                 (wikibase:sitelinks) 
                 (rdf:type)
                } 
    }#union

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ko,en" }
} ORDER BY ?p
```

Comment: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Adding_labels_for_properties

Comment: And again another reference on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383784/wikidata-get-all-properties-with-labels-and-values-of-an-item

Comment: Oh I see Thank you for your help