# Wikidata SPARQL queries returning different results after filtering for English labels

Tags: sparql, wikidata

My understanding of Wikidata SPARQL queries is that you can filter results for English labels in [two ways](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service).

1. Adding `SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }` to invoke a label service; or
2. Adding `?thing rdfs:label ?thingLabel FILTER (lang(?thingLabel) = "en")` for every output label.

I am running a query where I'm trying to get all properties of an entity in English. I followed a [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383784/wikidata-get-all-properties-with-labels-and-values-of-an-item/46385132) and came up with two queries.

Query 1: [Running this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FpropLabel%20%3Fstatement_property_objLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ24%29%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Fproperty%20%5B%3Fstatement_property%20%3Fstatement_property_obj%5D%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3Fproperty.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fstatement_property.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Call%20label%20service.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FpropLabel) takes returns **47** results.

```sql
SELECT ?itemLabel ?propLabel ?statement_property_objLabel
WHERE {

    VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q24)}

    ?item ?property [?statement_property ?statement_property_obj] .
    ?prop wikibase:claim ?property.
    ?prop wikibase:statementProperty ?statement_property.

    # Call label service.
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }

} ORDER BY ?propLabel
```

Query 2: [Running this query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FpropLabel%20%3Fstatement_property_objLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fitem%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ24%29%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Fproperty%20%5B%3Fstatement_property%20%3Fstatement_property_obj%5D%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3Fproperty.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fstatement_property.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20Call%20label%20service%20for%20each%20label.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement_property_obj%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fstatement_property_objLabel%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fstatement_property_objLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FpropLabel%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FpropLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FpropLabel) returns **35** results.

```sql
SELECT ?itemLabel ?propLabel ?statement_property_objLabel
WHERE {

    VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q24)}

    ?item ?property [?statement_property ?statement_property_obj] .
    ?prop wikibase:claim ?property.
    ?prop wikibase:statementProperty ?statement_property.

    # Call label service for each label.
    ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel FILTER (lang(?itemLabel) = "en") .
    ?statement_property_obj rdfs:label ?statement_property_objLabel FILTER (lang(?statement_property_objLabel) = "en") .
    ?prop rdfs:label ?propLabel FILTER (lang(?propLabel) = "en") .

} ORDER BY ?propLabel
```

Why is the second query returning fewer rows? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause is that the `wikibase:label` service returns label results for *any* value of `?statement_property_obj`, even if that value has no actual `rdfs:label` defined (it appears to just return the actual value of `?statement_property_obj` itself).

As an example, see the very first result in query 1, where `?statement_property_objLabel` is bound to `topic/Jack_Bauer`. This is not the value of an actual `rdfs:label` property in the data, just a 'fallback' value that the label service provides. So query 2, which *explicitly* queries for `rdfs:label` attributes, won't return this (and similar) results.