# Get all properties, sub-properties and label IDs from Wikidata item

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to write a query that returns all possible information from a wikidata page, as https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1299.
Ideally I would like to retrieve all info that are present in that page in english language.

So I am trying [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46385132/3426270):

```
SELECT ?wdLabel ?ps_Label ?wdpqLabel ?pq_Label WHERE {
  VALUES ?artist {
    wd:Q1299
  }
  ?artist ?p ?statement.
  ?statement ?ps ?ps_.
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p;
    wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?statement ?pq ?pq_.
    ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

which works quite fine but I would like to retrieve all wikidata ids on the **ps_Label** column.

For example here I have **Paul McCartney** as string and I would like to also have the wikidata ID associated to that item, which is [Q2599](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2599)

```
has part    Paul McCartney  start time  1960-01-01T00:00:00Z
has part    Paul McCartney  end time    1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
has part    Paul McCartney  object has role singer
has part    Paul McCartney  object has role instrumentalist
```

Something similar to this other below but I can't merge the two together as I am missing some hint on sub-properties here.

```
SELECT ?propUrl ?propLabel ?valUrl ?valLabel WHERE {
  wd:Q1299 ?propUrl ?valUrl.
  ?property ?ref ?propUrl;
    rdf:type wikibase:Property;
    rdfs:label ?propLabel.
  ?valUrl rdfs:label ?valLabel.
  FILTER((LANG(?valLabel)) = "en")
  FILTER((LANG(?propLabel)) = "en")
}
ORDER BY (?propUrl) (?valUrl)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: if you want to Wikidata ID of the `ps_Label` why are you not just selecting `?ps_` as well? I mean, just do `SELECT ?wdLabel ?ps_ ?ps_Label ?wdpqLabel ?pq_Label WHERE {` - done. Or are you asking for something different?

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t exactly what you’re asking for, but if you really just want all data on a single object, it is far easier and more economical to use the data access provided by https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q2599.json