# Wikidata get all properties of an item with units

Tags: generics, properties, sparql, wikidata

We are creating an application that use data from Wikidata services with Sparql queries.
The basic task is to get all properties of an item with corresponding units and precision.

There is a great sample of a query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383784/wikidata-get-all-properties-with-labels-and-values-of-an-item), but it lacks data on units and precision.
We added some details to this sample, but units are available only for specific property P2102.

So the question is - how to use not specific property (i.e. generic properties, unlike specific p:P2102, ps:P2102 or psv:P2102 in sample below) in Sparql generic queries like this ?

Here is a sample of our query :

```
SELECT ?wd ?wdLabel ?wdDescription ?ps_ ?ps_Label ?ps_Description ?wdpq ?wdpqLabel ?wdpqDescription ?pq_ ?pq_Label ?pq_Description ?bpUnit ?bpUnitLabel {
  VALUES (?itm) {(wd:Q407225)}
  
  ?itm ?p ?statement .
  ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .
  
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.
  ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.
  
  OPTIONAL {
  ?statement ?pq ?pq_ .
  ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq .
   
   ?itm p:P2102 [  # -- custom property unit
          ps:P2102 ?bp ;
          psv:P2102/wikibase:quantityUnit  ?bpUnit
        ].
  }  
  
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
} 
ORDER BY ?wd ?statement ?ps_
```

Comment: you can get the unit via the property qualifier node:

Comment: `SELECT ?wd ?wdLabel ?wdDescription ?ps_ ?ps_Label ?ps_Description ?wdpq ?wdpqLabel ?wdpqDescription ?pq_ ?pq_Label ?pq_Description ?pq_unit ?pq_unitLabel{
 VALUES (?itm) {(wd:Q407225)}
VALUES ?wd {wd:P2119}
?itm ?p ?statement .
 ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.
  ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.
  OPTIONAL {
  ?statement ?pq ?pq_ .
  ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq .
  ?wdpq wikibase:qualifierValue ?pqv .
  OPTIONAL {?statement ?pqv [wikibase:quantityUnit ?pq_unit]} }
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
ORDER BY ?wd ?statement ?ps_`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ?wd ?wdLabel ?wdDescription ?ps_ ?ps_Label ?ps_Description ?wdpq ?wdpqLabel 
       ?wdpqDescription ?pq_ ?pq_Label ?pq_Description ?pq_unit ?pq_unitLabel {  
    VALUES ?itm { wd:Q407225 } 
    VALUES ?wd { wd:P2119 } 
    ?itm ?p ?statement .  
    ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .   
    ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.   
    ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.   
    OPTIONAL {   
        ?statement ?pq ?pq_ .   
        ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq .   
        ?wdpq wikibase:qualifierValue ?pqv .   
        OPTIONAL { ?statement ?pqv [wikibase:quantityUnit ?pq_unit] } 
    } 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" } 
} ORDER BY ?wd ?statement ?ps_
```