# How to relate p[s[n]] and w[d[t]] properties in wikidata sparql query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get all quantitative values of a given wd:* entry including the statements details (qualifiers?) - foremost the unit, since most numeric values are useless without it.

I was able to come up with the following query to get all quantitative values:

```
SELECT ?p ?property ?propertyLabel ?propertyDescription ?v WHERE {
  wd:Q1726 ?p ?v.
  ?property wikibase:propertyType wikibase:Quantity;
    wikibase:directClaim ?p.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY ?v
```

| p | property | propertyLabel | propertyDescription | v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wdt:P2046 | wd:P2046 | area | area occupied by an object | 310.71 |

As you can see this is perfect to get the value of 310 km² as well as the labels and description of property you are looking for.

With the knowledge of the property being `wd[t]:2046`, I came up with a new query to get the value with quantifiers for it's best statement:

```
SELECT ?statement ?value ?valueLabel ?unit ?unitLabel WHERE {
  wd:Q1726 p:P2046 ?statement.
  ?statement psn:P2046 ?valuenode.
  ?valuenode wikibase:quantityAmount ?value.
  ?valuenode wikibase:quantityUnit ?unit.
  ?statement a wikibase:BestRank.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

| statement | value | valueLabel | unit | unitLabel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wds:Q1726-33fec614-441a-a6c4-06cd-b79490a52c4b | 310710000 | 310710000 | wd:Q25343 | square metre |

However I have no idea how to join these two queries to relate `?v` of the first one with `?statement` of the second one. In the end what I'm looking for is to add a unit column to the first query. All examples and explanations I've seen regarding quantifiers are searching for a given property and I'm struggling to understand how to relate `statement` with `statement/value-normalized/` and `statement/value/` or how to filter for a property to be one of those.

Comment: https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format

Comment: `SELECT ?wd ?wdLabel ?wdDescription ?valAmount ?valUnitLabel {
  VALUES ?item {
    wd:Q1726
  }
  ?item ?p ?stmt.
  ?stmt ?psv ?valNode.
  ?wd wikibase:propertyType wikibase:Quantity;
    wikibase:claim ?p ;
    wikibase:statementProperty ?ps ; 
    wikibase:statementValue ?psv .
  ?valNode wikibase:quantityUnit ?valUnit ;
           wikibase:quantityAmount ?valAmount

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY (?wd) (?stmt) (?ps_)` would give you all direct quantity values with unit.

Comment: for the statement qualifiers, you could just follow the `?ps` variable, similar to the query in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70609970/4744359