# How to get only the most recent value from a Wikidata property?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Suppose I want to get a list of every country (Q6256) and its most recently recorded Human Development Index (P1081) value. The Human Development Index property for the country contains a list of data points taken at different points in time, but I only care about the most recent data. This query will not work because it gets multiple results for each country (one for each Human Development Index data point):

```
SELECT
?country 
?countryLabel 
?hdi_value
?hdi_date
WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  OPTIONAL { ?country p:P1081 ?hdi_statement. 
         ?hdi_statement ps:P1081 ?hdi_value.
         ?hdi_statement pq:P585 ?hdi_date.
       }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[Link to Query Console](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%0A%3Fcountry%20%0A%3FcountryLabel%20%0A%3Fhdi_value%0A%3Fhdi_date%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20p%3AP1081%20%3Fhdi_statement.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fhdi_statement%20ps%3AP1081%20%3Fhdi_value.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fhdi_statement%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fhdi_date.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

I'm aware of GROUP BY/GROUP CONCAT but that will still give me every result when I'd prefer to just have one. GROUP BY/SAMPLE will also not work since SAMPLE is not guaranteed to take the most recent result.

Any help or link to a relevant example query is appreciated!

P.S. Another thing I'm confused about is why population P1082 in this query returns only one population result per country

```
SELECT
?country 
?countryLabel 
?population
WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P1082 ?population. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

while the same query but for HDI returns multiple results per country:

```
SELECT
?country 
?countryLabel 
?hdi
WHERE {
 ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P1081 ?hdi. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

What is different about population and HDI that causes the behavior to be different? When I view the population data for each country on Wikidata I see multiple population points listed, but only one gets returned by the query.

Comment: 1. Paste something like `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country p:P1081/pq:P585 ?hdi_date1 . FILTER (?hdi_date1 > ?hdi_date) }` *outside* of `OPTIONAL`.

Comment: 2. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100906/7879193

Comment: Try this for your first query :   SELECT DISTINCT   ?country ?countryLabel (MAX(?hdi_value) AS ?hd)  (MAX(?hdi_date) AS ?hde)
WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  OPTIONAL { ?country p:P1081 ?hdi_statement. 
             ?hdi_statement ps:P1081 ?hdi_value.
             ?hdi_statement pq:P585 ?hdi_date.
           }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}

GROUP BY ?country ?countryLabel

Comment: @Shubhangi, are you sure that HDI are just increasing for all the countries? I. e. that `MAX(hdi_value)` corresponds to `MAX(hdi_date)`?

Comment: @StanislavKralin I have checked for few countries and it was fine.

Comment: @Shubhangi, check for Venezuela

Comment: @StanislavKralin yes I have checked for Venezuela and it gives me the right answer as he wants the most recent result.

Comment: @Shubhangi, the right answer for Venezuela is 0.762, not 0.764.

Comment: Thank you both! Stanislav's answer works perfectly here. Unfortunately, Shubhangi's answer does not work when the most recent HDI is lower than a previous HDI as was the case with Venezuela.

Comment: @StanislavKralin oops yeah you are right I didn't see the very last digit of HDI for Venezuela.

Comment: @Shubhangi, full list of such countries (their maximal HDI is in the past): *Greece, Cyprus, Cuba, Belize, East Timor, Federated States of Micronesia, Venezuela, Saint Lucia, Jamaica, Honduras, Iraq, Oman, Syria, Central African Republic, South Sudan, Equatorial Guinea, The Gambia, Libya, Swaziland, State of Palestine*

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thank you for pointing out the mistakes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your questions are duplicates, but I'll try to add interesting facts to existing answers.

**Question 1** is a duplicate of  [SPARQL query to get only results with the most recent date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181713/sparql-query-to-get-only-results-with-the-most-recent-date).

This technique does the trick:

```
FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?country p:P1081/pq:P585 ?hdi_date_ .
    FILTER (?hdi_date_ > ?hdi_date)
}
```

However, you should add this clause *outside* of `OPTIONAL`, it is not working inside of `OPTIONAL` (and I'm not sure this is not a bug).

---

**Question 2** is a duplicate of [Some cities aren't instances of city or big city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100068/some-cities-arent-instances-of-city-or-big-city-odd-behaviour-of-wikidata)

You can't use wdt-predicates, because missing statements are not *truthy*.
  They are normal-rank statements, but there is a preferred-rank statement.

> Truthy statements represent statements that have the best non-deprecated rank for given property. Namely, if there is a preferred statement for property P2, then only preferred statements for P2 will be considered truthy. Otherwise, all normal-rank statements  are considered truthy.

The reason why `P1081` always has preferred statement is that this property is processed by [PreferentialBot](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:PreferentialBot).

Comment: I tried to do exactly what you described but on the cities - but doesn't look correct. SELECT

?city
?cityLabel
?cityPopulation
?hdi_date

WHERE {
#  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
#  OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P1082 ?population. }
  
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
  ?city p:P1082 ?populationStatement .
  ?populationStatement ps:P1082 ?cityPopulation.
    
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?city p:P1082/pq:P585 ?hdi_date_ .
    FILTER (?hdi_date_ > ?hdi_date)
 }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} order by ?countryLabel

Comment: @user702846, "exactly" would be rather something like this: https://w.wiki/EKB :)