# Overcoming single value constraing issues with P625 coordinate location in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get a city list together with region and country information with a query like this:

```
# get a list of cities
# for geograpy3 library
# see https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/issues/15
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
# get human settlements
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel (max(?cityPop) as ?cityPopulation) ?coord ?region ?regionLabel ?regionIsoCode ?country ?countryLabel ?countryIsoCode ?countryPopulation ?countryGdpPerCapita WHERE {
  # if you uncomment this line this query might run for some 3 hours on a local wikidata copy using Apache Jena
  # run for Vienna, Illinois, Vienna Austria, Paris Texas and Paris France as example only
  # VALUES ?city { wd:Q577544 wd:Q1741 wd:Q830149 wd:Q90}.
  # run for Andorra
  VALUES ?country {wd:Q228}.
  # instance of human settlement https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q486972
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q486972 .
  # label of the City
  ?city rdfs:label ?cityLabel filter (lang(?cityLabel) = "en").
  # country this city belongs to
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
  # label for the country
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel filter (lang(?countryLabel) = "en").
  # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P297 ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code
  ?country wdt:P297 ?countryIsoCode.
  # population of country
  ?country wdt:P1082 ?countryPopulation.
  OPTIONAL {
     ?country wdt:P2132 ?countryGdpPerCapita.
  }
  OPTIONAL {
     # located in administrative territory
     # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P131
     ?city wdt:P131* ?region.
     # administrative unit of first order
     ?region wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q10864048.
     ?region rdfs:label ?regionLabel filter (lang(?regionLabel) = "en").
     # isocode state/province
     OPTIONAL { ?region wdt:P300 ?regionIsoCode. }
  }
  # population of city
  OPTIONAL { ?city wdt:P1082 ?cityPop.}
   # get the coordinates
  OPTIONAL { ?city wdt:P625 ?coord. }
} GROUP BY  ?city ?cityLabel  ?coord ?region ?regionLabel ?regionIsoCode ?country ?countryLabel ?countryIsoCode ?countryPopulation ?countryGdpPerCapita
ORDER BY ?cityLabel
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20get%20a%20list%20of%20cities%0A%23%20for%20geograpy3%20library%0A%23%20see%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsomnathrakshit%2Fgeograpy3%2Fissues%2F15%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ps%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20pq%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fqualifier%2F%3E%0A%23%20get%20human%20settlements%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%28max%28%3FcityPop%29%20as%20%3FcityPopulation%29%20%3Fcoord%20%3Fregion%20%3FregionLabel%20%3FregionIsoCode%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FcountryIsoCode%20%3FcountryPopulation%20%3FcountryGdpPerCapita%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%23%20if%20you%20uncomment%20this%20line%20this%20query%20might%20run%20for%20some%203%20hours%20on%20a%20local%20wikidata%20copy%20using%20Apache%20Jena%0A%20%20%23%20run%20for%20Vienna%2C%20Illinois%2C%20Vienna%20Austria%2C%20Paris%20Texas%20and%20Paris%20France%20as%20example%20only%0A%20%20%23%20VALUES%20%3Fcity%20%7B%20wd%3AQ577544%20wd%3AQ1741%20wd%3AQ830149%20wd%3AQ90%7D.%0A%20%20%23%20run%20for%20Andorra%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fcountry%20%7Bwd%3AQ228%7D.%0A%20%20%23%20instance%20of%20human%20settlement%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FQ486972%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ486972%20.%0A%20%20%23%20label%20of%20the%20City%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcityLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FcityLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%23%20country%20this%20city%20belongs%20to%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20.%0A%20%20%23%20label%20for%20the%20country%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FcountryLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FProperty%3AP297%20ISO%203166-1%20alpha-2%20code%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP297%20%3FcountryIsoCode.%0A%20%20%23%20population%20of%20country%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3FcountryPopulation.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP2132%20%3FcountryGdpPerCapita.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20located%20in%20administrative%20territory%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FProperty%3AP131%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP131%2A%20%3Fregion.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20administrative%20unit%20of%20first%20order%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fregion%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ10864048.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fregion%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FregionLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FregionLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20isocode%20state%2Fprovince%0A%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fregion%20wdt%3AP300%20%3FregionIsoCode.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23%20population%20of%20city%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3FcityPop.%7D%0A%20%20%20%23%20get%20the%20coordinates%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoord.%20%7D%0A%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%20%3Fcoord%20%3Fregion%20%3FregionLabel%20%3FregionIsoCode%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FcountryIsoCode%20%3FcountryPopulation%20%3FcountryGdpPerCapita%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcityLabel)
to experiment with the query i comment out the

```
  # VALUES ?city { wd:Q577544 wd:Q1741 wd:Q830149 wd:Q90}.
  # run for Andorra
  VALUES ?country {wd:Q228}.
```

part to see that the results make sense.

Now for The Andorra trial there are cities with multiple coordinates:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P625
Which are event flagged as a problem.
[image: Wikidata Query Screenshot]

I know there is work-around as explained in [How to get only the most recent value from a Wikidata property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066390/how-to-get-only-the-most-recent-value-from-a-wikidata-property?rq=1) and https://w.wiki/EKB

I tried the approach in the snippet

```
?city p:P1082 ?populationStatement . 
  ?populationStatement ps:P1082 ?cityPopulation.
  ?populationStatement pq:P585 ?date
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?city p:P1082/pq:P585 ?date_ . FILTER (?date_ > ?date) }
```

which makes queries real slow and in this case i am looking into all instance of human settlement which are a few hundred thousand. Even on my local wikidata copy this runs more than 3 hours !

**So i wonder whether there is an alternative with MAX, AVG, Subqueries with limit or the like or any other nifty idea that would solve the issue with a decent performance?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sample()` as aggregation function [(sparql doc)](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates).

Starting from you query expression, you will need to change the first line into

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel (max(?cityPop) as ?cityPopulation) (sample(?coord) as ?coordinate) ?region ?regionLabel ?regionIsoCode ?country ?countryLabel ?countryIsoCode ?countryPopulation ?countryGdpPerCapita WHERE {
```

and your second last line into:

```
} GROUP BY  ?city ?cityLabel ?region ?regionLabel ?regionIsoCode ?country ?countryLabel ?countryIsoCode ?countryPopulation ?countryGdpPerCapita
```

The result should look like this: https://w.wiki/dRV.

The work-around you tried does not work because unlike P1082 (population), P625 (coordinate) have in most cases no P585 (point in time) qualifier.